# Find the norm of linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, lp-spaces

Let $p \in [1,\infty)$ and let $\Lambda$ be a linear functional on $L^P(I)$ denoted by

$$\Lambda(f) = \int_0^1 e^{2x} f(x) dx \;\;\; \text{for } f\in L^P(I).$$

where $I = [0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$. Use $\|f\|_{p}^p = \int_0^1 |f(x)|^pdx$ for $f \in L^P(I)$.

I show that

\begin{align*}
|\Lambda f| &= \bigg| \int_0^1 e^{2x} f(x) dx \bigg | \\
& \leq \int_0^1 |e^{2x} f(x)| dx \\
& \leq \|e^{2x}\|_q \|f(x)\|_p < \infty
\end{align*}

Therefore $\| \Lambda\| \leq \|e^{2x}\|_q$. I think I need to show that $\| \Lambda \| \geq \| e^{2x} \|_q$ to get norm of this linear functional. But I couldn't find a way to get that inequality. How could I find the norm of $\Lambda$.

++

By using the condition for equiality in Holder's inequality, let $f(x) = e^{2xq/p}$.

Then $| \Lambda f | = \|e^{2x}\|_q$. Therefore $\| \Lambda \| = \|e^{2x}\|_q$.

Comment: Do you know the condition for equality in Holder's inequality? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I add my solution. Do I properly use your help?

Comment: Actually, $\|f||\neq 1$ for your choice. But $|\Lambda f| =\|f\| \|e^{2x}\|$ and this gives the same conclusion.